# Language downloading within the application

Tags: iphone

I have a requirement in my app that the user will have a choice for downloading languages from paypal or something like that,is the any way for doing this in the app?
How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users can't modify your app binary, so I think you should put all of your localized files inside the app and somehow let the users to 'unlock' them by using **In-App Purchases**.

More info about In-App Purchases: [In-App Purchases Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)